# Change Kubernetes network route to internet

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, iptables, kubernetes-networking

Do you know how to configure default network route for Kubernetes to reach internet?
My cluster nodes (Ubuntu 18.04 with netplan) have 2 IP exposed on internet. When I installed Kubernetes, first IP was the default route, I changed default route to the second IP on system. But pods in Kubernetes continue to use first one to go on internet. Its don't use system configuration.
I have Kubernetes 1.17.5 with Canal network deployed with Rancher. I don't find if I should change a configuration or edit iptables of docker0 to tell Kubernetes which route to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can change default network interface by adding IP address to [`--apiserver-advertise-address`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-init/#options) flag in `kubeadm init`.

> The IP address the API Server will advertise it's listening on. If not set the default network
> interface will be used.

When you join nodes to your cluster make sure you add correct API server IP address

```
 kubeadm join --apiserver-advertise-address <ip-address-used-in-init> [any additional flags]
```

Comment: Ok, I guess the best is to delete and add again the node